# c++ return subclass where function returns pointer to superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am new to c++. I attached a uml diagram of what i have, my issue is with returning a class defined as a superclass, but i will actually be returning a class that extends it.

In the uml diagram, the superclass in question is Booking and the subclasses Single and Sharing which extend it.  I have a function addBooking([...]) in BookList class, which is where my issue is.
[image]

I defined Booking, and then 2 other subclasses which extend it being Single and Sharing.  My question is, can I return Single or Sharing class in the BookingList.addBooking([....]) function?
Both my subclasses initialise the super class, for example Single initialises it like this:

```
Single::Single(Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person g): Booking(c, a, d){[...]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may. Single and Sharing are of type Booking so returning a pointer to an instance of Single or Sharing as pointer to an instance of type Booking is completely legal.

Comment: Can i still access the extended classes variables?  From what i can see i don't think i can because since the return function returns the parent, I only have access to the parent information.

Comment: No, you cannot access the data of inherited class via a pointer/reference to a base class object. You need to down cast to inherited type in order to do that. Typically, when you have an instance of base type pointing to an instance of derived type, you're code relies on polymorphism to do its ask. Otherwise, your design is wrong and you ought to revise it. Please read this article carefully: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: Thanks for the help, i used polymorphism, works perfectly as what i would expect. I have a parent object and i access the child in the list using the *. ie.  `Booking *booking = bookingList.at(i);` and it gives me the derived objects values. Getting my head around pointers.